# Background music closes on taking picture from camera UIImagePicker

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

When I take picture from camera using UIImagePicker, background music (from ipod app, pandora app) stops. It's not happening for facebook app. Is there a separate delegate for this? Please help

Comment: Are you recording instead of taking a photo?

Comment: I don't see this problem with my own app either. You must be doing something extra in your app. Post the code causing the issue.

Comment: yes I'm playing click sound using **AVAudioPlayer**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be due to your Audio Session policy. Taking a picture makes a "click" noise. Perhaps this is causing all other sound to be stopped because of your Audio Session.

Comment: The OP says it stops audio from other apps (like the iPod app or Pandora), not his own app.

Comment: Yes, that's what an AVAudioSession does: it affects whether sounds in your app cause background sound from other apps to stop.

Comment: More info here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch27.html#_audio_session I'm not saying this the cause of the OP's problem for sure, but the notion "my app makes a sound and this causes background sound to stop playing" is very suggestive.